# android studio doesn't see so libs in jniLibs folder

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface

I have reinstalled windows recently.In my project I have some `so` libraries in `app\src\main\jniLibs\` before I reinstalled windows it was compiling fine but now when I building apk I got following error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders'.
Error: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: 
D:\android_dev\projects\puzzle\app\src\main\jniLibs\armeabi-v7a\libjs.so -> 
D:\android_dev\projects\puzzle\app\build\intermediates\jniLibs\release\armeabi-v7a\libjs.so
```

debug build fails as well

Android studio version:2.3.2

Comment: Probably after you reinstalled windows, the new user account cannot rewrite the files created with the old user account. You can try to use elevated Explorer or CMD to delete the intermediate files in your project (`del /s D:\android_dev\projects\puzzle\app\build`). Can you change the source files in your project at all? Maybe you must change the ownership of `D:\android_dev` and all its children.

Comment: Indeed there was permission conflict.I removed jniLibs folder and downloaded it again and now its compiling fine.Thanks!Could you post your comment as an answer so I could accept it?